url luncher in flutter
Launching lib\main.dart on 23021RAAEG in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':path_provider_android:parseDebugLocalResources'.


Could not resolve all files for configuration ':path_provider_android:androidApis'.
Failed to transform android.jar to match attributes {artifactType=android-platform-attr, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> Execution failed for PlatformAttrTransform: C:\Users\a\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-34\android.jar.
> C:\Users\a\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-34\android.jar


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.


Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 37s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
..iam trying to use flutter url luncher   and i get this when i add the dependencies

The error message indicates that there's an issue with the Android SDK platform version. The path_provider_android plugin is trying to use android-34, which might not be installed or could be corrupted.
